# Regex, Pandas and flagging rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to flag any records that contain User Defined "incorrect" characters. In this case, record two (2) should return as a Non-Valid Record, but I seem to be capturing either record 1 or 3. These would be deemed "correct". **Any suggestions on why these are flagging rather than "incorrect record"?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = {'HOME1': ['123 Main St', '567\ Country Road', 'PO Box 900']}
dft = pd.DataFrame(data)

from itertools import chain
chars =[]
acceptable = [x for x in chain(range(48,58),range(32,33), range(65,91), range(97,123))]
for ch in acceptable:
    chars.append(chr(ch))

reg_list = map(re.compile,chars)

for x in dft['HOME1']:
    print(x)
    if any(re.match(x) for re in reg_list):
        conditions = [dft['HOME1'].apply(lambda x: x)!=x, dft['HOME1'].apply(lambda x: x)==x]
        choices = [0,1]
        dft['NonValidHOME1'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=0)

try:
    print(dft.groupby(['NonValidHOME1'])[['HOME1']].filter(lambda x: len(x) ==1).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()))
except:
    print("no invalid Home1")
```

Comment: I think you need to remove `reg_list = map(re.compile,chars)` and replace `if any(re.match(x) for re in reg_list):` with `if any(c in x for c in chars):` (if `x` is a string). If you just check for a a single char from a list inside a string, you need no regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in dft['HOME1']:
for c in x:
    if c not in chars:
        print(c,x)
        conditions = [dft['HOME1'].apply(lambda x: x)==x, dft['HOME1'].apply(lambda x: x)!=x]
        choices = [1,0]
        dft['NonValidHOME1'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=0)

#[print(c) for x in dft['HOME1'] for c in x if c not in chars]
```

Thank you for the comment. That sent me on a "better" path or at least one that got me to an answer.